# How to make adjacent tiles combine seamlessly ?(2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, tiling

Ok ill get straight to the point, here is an image of what i want to achieve:
[image]

And here is an Image of what my game looks like:
[image]

What I'm referring to is how the tiles seamlessly "connect". As you can see, on the first image there is a slight fade from one tile to the next one, for example where the sand and grass meet. On the second image, my game, there is not fade and no transition and it looks very bad. Like when the grass changes colors, there is no fade/filtering.

I assume this is a fairly common problem, so is there any assets from the asset store that solve this problem, or any built in solution within Unity? (Without writing own own custom script, of course) If there isnt any, how do I go about creating this filtering/transition between the tiles?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to draw them on your own in some software and then importing it in Unity, other way to do it is to make them overlay where the transition is and put 50% opacity on both layers just where they are overlaping, this will give you small effect of transition.